# dataflow job failing after taking too long to execute

Tags: go, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm running a basic pipeline in Go, just a Read and Write and after 1 HOUR OF EXECUTION, it fails. The job is created successfully on google dataflow service and then it failed.

```sh
go run pipeline.go \
--input gs://beam-in/raw.txt \
--output gs://beam-out/output \
--runner dataflow \
--project my-project-id \
--region us-central1 \
--temp_location gs://beam-out/temp/ \
--staging_location gs://beam-out/binaries/ \
--worker_harness_container_image=apache/beam_go_sdk:latest
```

```golang
 Submitted job: 2021-02-25_13_13_29-1267817619179399940
 Job state: JOB_STATE_PENDING
 Job still running ...
 Job still running ...
 Job still running ...
 ...
```

pipeline.go

```golang
func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    beam.Init()

    if *output == "" {
        log.Fatal("No output provided")
    }

    p := beam.NewPipeline()
    s := p.Root()

    data := textio.Read(s, *input)
    textio.Write(s, *output, data)

    if err := beamx.Run(context.Background(), p); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to execute job: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: First a warning: Dataflow doesn't officially support Go yet, and the Dataflow runner isn't yet ready for general use.

But with that said, this pipeline is so basic that it seems like it should work. The fact that it executes for 1 hour before failing indicates that it's hanging somewhere and timing out. Are there any logs in Dataflow's log explorer for the job that might indicate where it's hanging?

Comment: @DanielOliveira, no it doesn't provide any logs. Thanks for taking the time and make a comment. I'll be looking forward for the time when the support for the Go language will be better.

Comment: Are you sure there's none? Did you check [the other log types](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#navigating_to) beyond step logs by opening up the external link to the logs explorer?

Comment: I just check all of them. I didn't get any message (I opened the external link and made some queries).

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: @RobertBurke, Apache Beam SDK for Go 2.29.0.dev

Comment: OK. Very unexpected then. Thank you for the report.
Have you tried the wordcount example? Does that work for you? Your pipeline is simpler than that, but we do know wordcount functions due to the beam integration tests.

Comment: This has been my experience playing with the starter guide (wordcount). https://luillyfe.medium.com/apache-beam-getting-started-golang-panic-by-panic-a68bd76ff3b0

Comment: I couldn't make it work either. Let me know if I am taking a misleading approach.

Comment: I gave the code a try with the same parameters (as close as I could) and haven't been able to replicate the hanging issue. I tried it with the latest commit from Go 2.29.0.dev as well (I was caught up to the latest commit in master today) and it ran successfully. Without any kinds of logs or a way to replicate the issue I can't think of anything else to try, sorry.